# stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document error

Tags: javascript, selenium, npm, mocha.js, nodes

After update to my selenium from 3.0.0 to 4.0.0 facing "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document " error from my existing test cases . Using mocha + chai frame work . earlier i didn't observe this error ... is this because of latest selenium 4.0.0 ? i am using node 12.18.3 and node package manager 7.5.4 ... facing the same error in chrome and edge driver's ... any idea on how to solve this one ... tried timeout , sleep etc but no luck

Many thanks ....

Comment: Please add ljnenof code where you get the error

Comment: var cell = driver.findElement(By.xpath('XXX'));
    return cell.getAttribute('class').then(function(classes){
      if(classes.includes('active editable')){
        driver.actions()
  .sendKeys(text).perform();
      }
    });  
it('Enter a value for a cell', done => {
     setTimeout(function () { 
     sendKeysOnSlicGrid(driver,10,1,'\uE016').then(function(){
       done();
      });
    },small);
   });

Comment: what happen if you add a sleep , why are you not use await ?

Comment: Could you please let me know where i need to use sleep/wait here . i added settimeout with small(10000 ms) in it block .....

Comment: According to [this][1], no changes that affect your code you put in a comment (and that I *strongly* suggest to add to the question on top using edit button) has been made.

You should re-check your code or your HTML if it is changed; also for javascript you really have to switch to **async/await**.

Have a look [here][2], it's easy.


  [1]: https://applitools.com/blog/selenium-4/?utm_campaign=%5BBlog%5D-What%27s-New-In-Selenium-4?&utm_medium=Syndication&utm_source=Medium&utm_term=CAT&utm_content=Blog
  [2]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4ql-QWKlwk